# Can dedicated memory be released on the GPU using OpenCL?

Tags: c++, c++14, opencl

Is there a way to free up dedicated memory when a function that runs on GPU using OpenCL ends? I have noticed that if you repeatedly call a program that uses OpenCL in GPU and it ends, a certain amount of dedicated memory is not released, which would cause an error if the function is called too many times.

UPDATE 22/12/2019:

I enclose a fragment of the code that is within the iteration. The configuration of the cl_program and cl_context is done outside the iteration:

```c
void launch_kernel(float * blockC, float * blockR, float * blockEst, float * blockEstv, float * blockL, cl_program program, cl_context context, std::vector<cl_device_id> deviceIds, int n){

    cl_kernel kernel_function = clCreateKernel(program, "function_example", &error);

    cl_event event;

    cl_command_queue queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, (deviceIds)[0], 0, &error);
    std::size_t size[1] = { (size_t)n };

    cl_mem blockCBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(float) * (n * s), (void *)&blockC[0], &error);
    cl_mem blockRBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(float) * (n * s), (void *)&blockR[0], &error); 
    cl_mem blockEstBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, sizeof(float) * n, (void *)&blockEst[0], &error); 
    cl_mem blockEstvBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, sizeof(float) * n, (void *)&blockEstv[0], &error); 
    cl_mem blockLBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, sizeof(float) * n, (void *)&blockL[0], &error); 

    clSetKernelArg(kernel_solution, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &blockCBuffer);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel_solution, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &blockRBuffer);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel_solution, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &blockEstBuffer);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel_solution, 3, sizeof(cl_mem), &blockEstvBuffer);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel_solution, 4, sizeof(cl_mem), &blockLBuffer);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel_solution, 5, sizeof(int), &s);

    openclSingleton->checkError(clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel_function, 1, nullptr, size, nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr));
    clEnqueueMapBuffer(queue, blockEstBuffer, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ, 0, n * sizeof(float) , 0, nullptr, nullptr, &error);
    clEnqueueMapBuffer(queue, blockEstvBuffer, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ, 0, n * sizeof(float) , 0, nullptr, nullptr, &error);
    clEnqueueMapBuffer(queue, blockLBuffer, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ, 0, n * sizeof(float) , 0, nullptr, nullptr, &error);

    clReleaseMemObject(blockCBuffer);
    clReleaseMemObject(blockRBuffer);
    clReleaseMemObject(blockEstBuffer);
    clReleaseMemObject(blockEstvBuffer);
    clReleaseMemObject(blockLBuffer);

    clFlush(queue);
    clFinish(queue);
    clWaitForEvents(1, &event);

    clReleaseCommandQueue(queue);   
    clReleaseKernel(kernel_function);
}
```

UPDATE 23/12/2019

Updated the code with the iterative process that calls the function in OpenCl. The problem arises when at the end of the launch_kernel function it leaves some dedicated memory used, which causes that if the variable m is too large, the memory becomes full and the program crashes due to lack of resources.

```c
std::vector<cl_device_id> deviceIds;
cl_program program;
cl_context context;

... //configuration program and context

int n;
float *blockEst, *blockEstv, *blockL, *blockC, *blockR;

for(int i = 0; i < m; m++){

    blockC = (float*)std::malloc(sizeof(float)*n*s);
    blockR = (float*)std::malloc(sizeof(float)*n*s);
    blockEst = (float*)std::malloc(sizeof(float)*n);
    blockEstv = (float*)std::malloc(sizeof(float)*n);
    blockL = (float*)std::malloc(sizeof(float)*n);

    .... //Set values blockC and blockR 

    launch_kernel(blockC, blockR, blockEst, blockEstv, blockL, program, context, deviceIds, n);

    ... //Save value blockEst, blockEstv and blockL

    std::free(blockC);
    std::free(blockR);
    std::free(blockEst);
    std::free(blockEstv);
    std::free(blockL);

}

clReleaseProgram(program);
clReleaseContext(context);
clReleaseDevice(deviceIds[0]);
```

Comment: Can you produce a [mcve]?  Is it possible you are leaking resources?

Comment: OpenCL has functions that allocate / copy / deallocate global memory. If you have a leak that's your bug.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Update the question. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: @slifer now be **explicit** about how (a) you induce the effect, and (b) how you measure the effect.  I cannot tell if you are repeatedly running an executable, or a function, or what.

Comment: @ALX23z Try decreasing some variables that are declared in the program in OpenCL and the dedicated memory that is used decreased, but the error still persists. I guess the error is caused because the private memory of the program is not released properly.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Update the Question. Thank you for your help and patience.

Comment: You release buffers before completing the kernel. That's UB or something.